# R-markdown: Add an empty line between echoed code and result output

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pre

To combine the echoed R code and outputted result in `knitr` there is a handy `collapse=TRUE` option. However by default it leaves no space between them i.e. given the following Rmd:

````
```{r, echo=TRUE, include=TRUE, collapse=TRUE}
x <- matrix(1:6, nrow=2)
x
```
````

It would produce this output wrapped in a `<pre>` tag:

```
x <- matrix(1:6, nrow=2)
x
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    1    3    5
## [2,]    2    4    6
```

What I would like instead is to get an empty line separating the output and code, but still being combined into a single `<pre>` element.

```
x <- matrix(1:6, nrow=2)
x

##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    1    3    5
## [2,]    2    4    6
```

Is there a way to achieve this? I tried adding an empty line to the end of the R chunk, but seems like it was removed.

Comment: You can use `cat('\n')`

Comment: @akrun but wouldn't then `cat('\n')` would appear in the echoed code too?

Comment: yes, didn't saw the echo part.  why do you need this space

Comment: @akrun just visual preference really. When plotting a lot of code that way it is a bit hard to separate where code ends and output begins. And with `collapse=FALSE` they are too much separated, since in the css pre has distinct background. Empty line would be a best middle option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a new chunk option instead of `collapse` using knitr chunk hooks that collapses code and output with additional whitespace. For instance, you could include in the setup chunk:

#### Rmarkdown

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
hook_chunk = knitr::knit_hooks$get('chunk')

knitr::knit_hooks$set(chunk = function(x, options) {
  regular_output = hook_chunk(x, options)
  # collapse with vspace if collapse_vspace is TRUE
  if (isTRUE(options$collapse_vspace))
    gsub("```\n\n```", "", regular_output)
  else
    regular_output
})

knitr::opts_chunk$set(collapse_vspace = TRUE)
```

```{r, echo = TRUE}
x <- matrix(1:6, nrow=2)
x
```
````

#### HTML output

[image: htmloutput]

Some useful references:

- [Hooks - Customizable functions to run before/after a code chunk, tweak the output, and manipulate chunk options](https://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/)
- [How to Create New Chunk Options in R Markdown](https://ulyngs.github.io/blog/posts/2019-02-01-how-to-create-your-own-chunk-options-in-r-markdown/)

Comment: This is a great solution. But if you are trying to `spin()` an R document, rather than to `knit()` an Rmd document, a tweak is in order: change `gsub("```\n\n```", "", regular_output)` to `gsub("```\n\n```r?", "", regular_output)`. The latter command should work with both Rmd documents and R documents that you are trying to spin/knit.

Answer (score 4):

````
```{r, echo=-3, include=TRUE, collapse=TRUE}
x <- matrix(1:6, nrow = 2)

x
```
````

this will add a space and `echo = -3` will not return the third line, therefore returning:

```
x <- matrix(1:6, nrow = 2)

##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    1    3    5
## [2,]    2    4    6
```

Comment: thanks, this is nice work around. Will probably accept soon. But maybe you know if it's possible to specify for echo to always exclude the last line, rather than providing an index like "-3" ?